# How to preserve items that's present in two or more arrays and return an array of that?

Tags: javascript, typescript, merge

so I'm trying to write a function that would preserve items that's present in two or more arrays only if the items have occurred in two or more arrays.

```
E.g.,
a = ["Amy", "Sheldon", "Raj"]
b = ["Amy", "Penny", "Leonard"]
c = ["Amy", "Penny", "Howard"]
```

The outcome should be ["Amy", "Penny"] because their occurrences are 2 or more.

Right now, I have a method that going against every array and compare to every other array, which is super slow. I'm merging multiple arrays and each array might have up to 10000 objects.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to preserve order? (If so, is it guaranteed that `["A", "B"]` followed by `["B", "A"]` is impossible, or should one take priority?)

Comment: You'll need to go over every array. Consider creating an object whose keys are the values and values are a count of how many times the key occurs. Then build a new array where the values are 2 or greater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the arrays and create an object of values and how many times they occur, then iterate over the result to gather values that occurred twice or more, e.g.

```js
var a = ["Amy", "Sheldon", "Raj", "Raj"]
var b = ["Amy", "Penny", "Leonard"]
var c = ["Amy", "Penny", "Howard"]

// Create object of value:count
var counts = [a,b,c].reduce(function(acc, arr) {

  // Remove duplicates from array
  arr = arr.filter(function(value, i){
    return arr.indexOf(value) == i;
  });
  
  // Add to and increment accumulator
  arr.forEach(function(value) {
    acc[value] = (acc[value] || 0) + 1;
  });
  return acc;   
},Object.create(null));

// Create array of value where count > 1
var result = Object.keys(counts).filter(function(key){
  return counts[key] > 1;
});

console.log(result); // Amy, Penny
                     // Raj not included as only in 1 array
```

If you can depend on support for modern features, then the following may suit:

```js
var a = ["Amy", "Sheldon", "Raj"];
var b = ["Amy", "Penny", "Leonard"];
var c = ["Amy", "Penny", "Howard"];


var counts = [a, b, c].reduce((acc, arr) => {
  arr.filter(function(value, i){
    return arr.indexOf(value) == i;
  }).forEach(value => acc[value] = (acc[value] || 0) + 1);
  return acc;
}, Object.create(null));

var result = Object.keys(counts).filter(key => counts[key] > 1);

console.log(result);
```

Note that this may not preserve order. If you need order to be guaranteed, use a [*Map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of an Object for *counts* as it will maintain insertion order.

The use of `Object.create(null)` means that the accumulator has no properties, obviating the requirement for a *hasOwnProperty* test at:

```
acc[value] = (acc[value] || 0) + 1;
```

Comment: These will report elements which occur twice or more in one input array, but not in any of the others.

Comment: I guess that should be okay since we can always combine multiple arrays into one array. I'm actually having a little bit of problems rewriting the above Javascript code into TypeScript, any hints? more specifically, I don't know the line after "return acc", the "}, {});" should be what type in Typescript.

Comment: Umm i wonder what happens when you have only one array with multiple items and only return items that occur two times or more..? should i get rid of the forEach?

Comment: @JamesLeigh—just remove the "Remove duplicates from array" code. It will work fine on a single array.