# How to get the count of property which has same value?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a json which is retrieved through the api as follows,

http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=3d6078cbb11e7e5b3989320ff1cc00c1

I am looping through the result set and creating a ticket object as follows,

```
 data.ticket.seating.forEach((seat: any) => {
                this.listings.push({ section: seat.section, selling: data.price.selling, amount: data.ticket.amount, type: data.ticket.type, row: seat.row });
                this.barChartLabels.push(data.price.selling);
                this.barChartData[0].data.push() // how to push the count of tickets which has the same price.
            });
```

In the above code, how to get the number of tickets which has the same price ? Also how to get the max price among all tickets?

Comment: Only for understanding: You want to group the tickets by price?

Comment: What have you tried? Answers here should give you a hint: [*How to preserve items that's present in two or more arrays and return an array of that?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42336471/how-to-preserve-items-thats-present-in-two-or-more-arrays-and-return-an-array-o)

Comment: @floriangosse yes group the tickets by price

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a hash table with keys being your ticket price and values being array of tickets with that price. For example:

```
var price_table = {};
entries.forEach((data: any) => {
    if(!price_table.hasOwnProperty(data.ticket.price.original))
        price_table[data.ticket.price.original] = [];
    price_table[data.ticket.price.original].push(data);
});
```

After running that code, you'll have to through the keys of `price_table` and find a max value among them:

```
var max = 0;
for(var price in price_table){
    if(price_table.hasOwnProperty(price)) {
        if(price >= max){
            max = price;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can you the max value to show the list of tickets with the highest price: `price_table[max]`

The above example considers you have proper values (numbers) for `data.ticket.price.original`.